# How do I bring this camera to life? 02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera

Tags: broadcom, mac, pci

This is the camera in my mac: 02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera
The computer is a macbook air, running Ubuntu 20.04. The camera is apparently a pci device. Searches are leading me in circles, going nowhere.
Is there a way to get this camera working/recognized?

Comment: Which Mac are you trying to get fully configured with Ubuntu? Some are easier than others …

Comment: the target computer is a macbook air, later 2015 vintage. I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on it and it seems to work well. I have gotten the wireless connection to work, but so far the camera is not recognized.

Comment: In that case, you’ll need [Patrik Jakobssen’s tools](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Get-Started#get-started-on-debian). He’s done a remarkable amount of work to get the basic hardware working with Ubuntu, and I can confirm this stuff works with 2012 and 2015-era MacBook Pros. It should work for the Air as well.

Comment: to Matigo...am indebted to you. This information will take some studying and experimenting to see if I get it right. I'm little better than a monkey in front of a typewriter, but will give it a go.

Comment: Am having a rough go of this. Thought I was doing well, but have hit a wall in the installation stage...will try another tack tomorrow.

Comment: It can be a right pain, yes. What's worse is that you'll need to recompile a number of drivers every time there's a kernel update, too, so be ready for constant admin work. In the end I opted to have  hardware run  software and picked up some off-lease Ubuntu-certified Lenovo notebooks for a great price for my Linux needs. Have had zero hardware issues for years ...

Comment: I guess this means I will be driven to learn more about the command-line. This may be my crossword-sudoku. Thank-you for your help in pointing me to some tools.

Comment: to Matigo...I now know this project is a bit beyond my skill level and will do some homework. What I think I should find out now is if there is any housecleaning to do after this failed attempt. Are there any stray bits and bytes lying about, so to speak, that might cause mischief? Do I need to tidy up any mess...and if so, how?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything that causes damage, no. I've used Patrik's tools for quite some time and he doesn't put out malicious or poor-quality stuff. If you were unable to make the camera work, you should be fine deleting the source files you downloaded. There may be small config and library files here and there but, if they're non-operational, there should be no issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not doubt the quality of Patrik's tools. I simply do not yet have the skills needed to use them, hence my need to do more homework on the command line and its language. If you ever need anything involving a large hammer or a shovel, I'm your guy.